# how to get aws lambda invocation count using javascript sdk

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to get invocation count for each of my lambda functions for a specific time range. I have used cloudwatch sdk to implement this. However I am getting a Metrics array but there is no data regarding the invocation count. My code.

```
var cwparams = {
  Namespace: "AWS/Lambda",
  MetricName: "Invocations",
};

const cw = await cloudWatch.listMetrics(cwparams).promise();
console.log(cw.Metrics);
```

My output

```
ResponseMetadata: { RequestId: 'some-id' },
  Metrics: [
    {
      Namespace: 'AWS/Lambda',
      MetricName: 'Invocations',
      Dimensions: [Array]
    },
    ... more objects like above
    ]
OwningAccounts: []
```

Dimensions array contains like this

```
{ Name: 'FunctionName', Value: 'us-east-1.xxxx-xxxx' },
{ Name: 'Resource', Value: 'us-east-1.xxx-xxxx:xxx' }
```

How do I get my desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.You can use **CloudWatch GetMetricStatistics** API to retrieve Invocation/Duration for a specific time range and for a specific lambda function.For details, have a look at [GetMetricStatistics AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricStatistics.html)

Pasted my answer below.

```
const params = {
    Namespace: "AWS/Lambda",
    MetricName: "Invocations",
    StartTime: "2023-01-04T00:00:00Z",
    EndTime: "2023-01-04T23:59:59Z",
    Period: 86400, // in seconds
    Statistics: ["Maximum", "Minimum", "Average"],
    Dimensions: [
      {
        Name: "FunctionName",
        Value: "your-lambda-function-name",
      },
    ],
  };
const cw = await cloudWatch.getMetricStatistics(params).promise();
```